# How can I decode/encode huffman trees in zlib?

Tags: c++, encoding, zlib, huffman-code

I have been searching the internet but could not find any information on how to use zlib in MSVC++ for encoding/decoding a huffman tree.

Question:  How can I use zlib to decode and encode a huffman tree.  Also, is there anyway to identify that a piece of gibberish is actually a huffman tree?

You can identify zlib by the following:

```
78 01 - No Compression/low
78 9C - Default Compression
78 DA - Best Compression
```

Is the same for huffman?  Thanks! (this has two questions into one!)

Comment: Maybe the section "advanced functions" in http://www.zlib.net/manual.html is what you're looking for? That one has some info on `Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY`.

Answer (score 1):

As written, your question is nonsensical.  zlib encodes and decodes very particular Huffman trees using very particular schemes for their representation as defined in the deflate format.  There is no generic thing called a Huffman tree with some specific definition that you can write an encoder and decoder for.

zlib provides no external functions for just the Huffman code handling.  That is integrated in the compression and decompression code.